# ExecuteScalar with WHERE clause not matching all rows

Tags: c#, ms-access, oledb, oledbcommand, executescalar

I have been researching why my below OleDBCommand ExecuteScalar function is not properly returning the correct data.

```
query = "SELECT Count(*) FROM NoteTable WHERE SQLMigrationFl <> 'Y'";
command = new OldDbCommand(query, connection);
var remainingNotes = (int)command.ExecuteScalar();
```

My connection is defined previously, and is successfully used by other queries.  My Access database has 99 records in it; however, when I run the above code it only returns 10. When I remove the WHERE statement it returns all 99; however, that will not help when the SQLMigrationFl begins to be populated with a 'Y'.  Any thoughts on why the ExecuteScalar function is not returning what I expect it to?

Thanks

Comment: If your `SQLMigrationFl` column can contain NULL values then you'll need to test for that condition, too. `WHERE SQLMigrationFl <> 'Y'` will not match rows where `SQLMigrationFl IS NULL`.

Comment: Yup, just changed my code to check for the nulls.  If you would like to leave that as the answer, I will accept it. 

Do you know why SQLMigrationFl <> 'Y' does not pick up nulls?

Comment: Any test with a `null` value (except `IS NULL`) will return `false` by design. So even though a null is not a 'Y', it will not match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `SQLMigrationFl` column can contain NULL values then you'll need to test for that condition, too. `WHERE SQLMigrationFl <> 'Y'` will not match rows where `SQLMigrationFl IS NULL` because NULL values are never equal (or *unequal*) to any other value. That is,

`NULL = 'Y'` is `false`, but
`NULL <> 'Y'` is also `false`, and even
`NULL = NULL` is `false`, which is why we need to use `WHERE ... IS NULL` to test for NULL values.